# "scripting" vim using python with greater granularity

Tags: python, linux, vim, scripting, tty

I'm attempting to write a python script that can automate vim, but the python vim interface doesn't give me enough power to do everything I need.  I want to communicate with vim as if my script were a tty (able to issue "visual mode" instructions etc). As far as vim is concerned, my script is a human running xterm (or whatever). Can this be done without building my own terminal emulator in python?

Comment: Can't you do things like `:exec "normal V2jx"` from that python interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All non-vimscript interfaces are cursed: the only way to communicate with vim (unless you want to edit/get contents of a buffer which is available using buffer object) are `execute` (`vim.command(string)` in python) and `eval` (`vim.eval(string)` in python), both requiring serializing arguments. If you want to just start visual mode use

```
vim.command("normal! V")
```

or

```
vim.eval("feedkeys('V')")
```

. But if you want, for example, to return some value to a caller function you will have to use

```
import json
# Some code that puts result into variable r
# This won't work if r contains non-unicode strings,
# you will have to write your own serializer in this case.
# As far as I know, it will also fail if some characters in the string
# can be represented only using surrogate pairs.
vim.command("let reply=".json.dumps(r))
# Now in the caller function variable l:reply is defined
```